# Drupal 7, how to span html/markup in a submit element?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming

Ive created the a button

```
$form['submit'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => 'verify',
 '#tree' => TRUE,
);
```

And I have added some markup code

```
 $form['submit']['verify'] array(
 '#markup' => 'example text',
 );
```

The button and the markup text display correctly as individual elements.

But I would like to replace the verify value in the submit element with the markup text. I cant just change the text because the markup is going to contain html.

Ive tried making the markup a variable, tried making it a child element. everything I can think of. But I just cant get the button to span around the markup.

Any advise is appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear from your question and what do you mean I can just change the text

Comment: the submit element doesnt allow html, so I cant style the text. But the markup does allow html elements which is why I would like to nest the markup text in the submit element.

Comment: You meant to do `<input type="submit">markup element here</input>` ?

Comment: @codingbiz: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form['submit'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => 'verify',
 '#tree' => TRUE,
 '#prefix' => '<div class="fancy-submit">',
 '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

I'm wondering why you don't use css with default classes to implement the styling though.